# Why does impersonating a process return "The directory name is invalid"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a process that needs to run under administrative privileges. I need the average joe to run the process, but I don't want to give everyone access... so I've created a simple class that will run this ONE task as an administrator, using impersonation.

The code is VERY striaght-forward, but I can't understand why this is crashing. HELP??!!

I'm running this via a batch file, and I've even copied the file that needs to execute to the local hard drive, thinking this might be a permission issue for running an app over the network.

```
    public static Process ImpersonateProcess(string exe, string args, string Username, string Password)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(exe);
        psi.Arguments = args;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.UserName = Username;

        psi.Password = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in Password.ToCharArray())
        {
            psi.Password.AppendChar(c);
        }

        Process proc = null;

        Console.WriteLine("starting...");
        proc = Process.Start(psi);
        Console.WriteLine("started");

        return proc;
    }
```

In the code above, I never get to "started". It throws an error in the Process.Start(psi) and with an error message of "the directory name is invalid."

Comment: are you sure that the exe name you provided is correct? Can you print it before starting the process and double check?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It could be because you're not setting the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property. According to the
docs:

> **Important Note:**
>
> The WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName and Password are provided. If the property is not set, the default working directory is %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.

Comment: I totally missed that little catch. =) THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH. It works like a charm now. It used to work because there was a security issue here where EVERYONE had access to system32. They patched that recently.

Comment: Manually setting the WorkingDirectory property fixed this for me in a very similar situation to the original question, though I have no idea why. All I did was explicitly set it to the expanded value of what Microsoft says is the default anyway (i.e. C:\Windows\System32). What's more, I was only having this problem with one application. Another application using the exact same code didn't need to set the WorkingDirectory property to work. It does seem that the whole Process.Start behaviour is just confusing.